# NPE when responses are referenced from external yaml files

Tags: java, yaml, openapi

I'm splitting YAML files, however I'm getting the following exception while generation code:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.swagger.v3.parser.ResolverCache.updateLocalRefs(ResolverCache.java:162)
    at io.swagger.v3.parser.ResolverCache.loadRef(ResolverCache.java:152)
    at io.swagger.v3.parser.processors.ExternalRefProcessor.processRefToExternalResponse(ExternalRefProcessor.java:205)
    at io.swagger.v3.parser.processors.ResponseProcessor.processReferenceResponse(ResponseProcessor.java:76)
    at io.swagger.v3.parser.processors.ResponseProcessor.processResponse(ResponseProcessor.java:38)
    at io.swagger.v3.parser.processors.OperationProcessor.processOperation(OperationProcessor.java:56)
    at io.swagger.v3.parser.processors.PathsProcessor.processPaths(PathsProcessor.java:83)
    at io.swagger.v3.parser.OpenAPIResolver.resolve(OpenAPIResolver.java:49)
    at io.swagger.v3.parser.OpenAPIV3Parser.readLocation(OpenAPIV3Parser.java:53)
    at io.swagger.parser.OpenAPIParser.readLocation(OpenAPIParser.java:19)
```

A sample of what I'm trying to achieve (`openapi.yaml`):

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: Common Data Types
  version: "1.0"
paths:
  /{appId}/subscriptions:
    get:
      summary: read all of the active subscriptions for the app

      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK (Successful)
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/subscription'
        '400':
          $ref: './common.yam#/components/responses/E400'
        '401':
          $ref: './common.yam#/components/responses/E401'
components:
  schemas:
    subscription:
      type: string
```

and `common.yaml`:

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: Common Data Types
  version: "1.0"
paths: {}
components:
 responses:
    E400:
      description: Bad request
    E401:
      description: Unauthorized
```

Context:

```
$ tree
├── common.yaml
└── openapi.yaml
$ openapi-generator version
3.3.0
```

*Observations*:
One observation is that, if 'schemas' is referred from external file insted of 'responses', the code generation works.
So ! What's the issue if 'responses' being referred from external yaml file?

The following *works*: - 'schemas' referred externally instead of 'response' (`openapi.yaml`):

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: Common Data Types
  version: "1.0"
paths:
  /{appId}/subscriptions:
    get:
      summary: read all of the active subscriptions for the app

      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK (Successful)
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: './common.yam#/components/schemas/subscription'
        '400':
          $ref: '#/components/responses/E400'
        '401':
          $ref: '#/components/responses/E401'
components:
 responses:
    E400:
      description: Bad request
    E401:
      description: Unauthorized
```

and `common.yaml`:

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: Common Data Types
  version: "1.0"
paths: {}
components:
  schemas:
    subscription:
      type: string
```

context:

```
$ tree
.
├── common.yaml
└── openapi.yaml
$ openapi-generator version
3.3.0
```

Comment: THERE IS NO NEED TO SHOUT, [so] has **other** ways to *emphasize* things. You should also not lazily lump filename, YAML, commandline commands+output together in one code block and make it difficult to recognise where one ends, and the other starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is fixed in `openapi-generator-cli-4.0.0-beta3`.

However, for `3.3.0` version below would work

What I observed is that the if common.yaml file below, causing the issue, is modified to common_modified.yaml, the issue is resolved and no Null pointer exception.

YAML causing issue `common.yaml`

```
openapi: 3.0.0
    info:
      title: Common Data Types
      version: "1.0"
    paths: {}
    components:
     responses:
        E400:
          description: Bad request
        E401:
          description: Unauthorized
```

Modified YAML fixing the issue `common_modified.YAML`

```
openapi: 3.0.0
    info:
      title: Common Data Types
      version: "1.0"
    paths: {}
    components:
     responses:
        E400:
          description: Bad request
          content:
            applictaion/json:  
        E401:
          description: Unauthorized
          content:
            applictaion/json:
```

It seems that the open API looks for content if referred externally. NOT SURE THOUGH. BUT works for me!